# Hyperref: Both Bibliography and Index entries in ToC are linked to Bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, hyperref

### Problem Statement

I use `BibTeX` for the Bibliography, `makeindex` for the Index and `hyperref` to create the hyperlinks.

In the `.pdf` file that I get after compiling, all hyperlinks (e.g., ToC entries, page references in the Index, citations of Bibliography entries,...) work, except for the Index entry in the ToC, which instead points to the Bibliography (the Bibliography ToC entry also links to the Bibliography).

### How to reproduce the problem

Here is my `example.tex` file, reduced to a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\nocite{*}

\frontmatter

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section\index{section}}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-2]

Cite-example\cite{ref1}

\backmatter

\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

and my `biblio.bib` file:

```
@book{ref1,
  author = "Author",
  title  = "Title",
  year   = 1490
}
```

Finally, here is the routine I use in compiling (I am running TeXLive in GNU/Linux Fedora20):

```
pdflatex example.tex
makeindex example.idx
bibtex example.aux
pdflatex example.tex
pdflatex example.tex
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this may be related to the use of `tocbibind`; see [wrong hyperref for Index in tableofcontents since TeXlive 2010](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138973/579)

Comment: You could manually add the correct entry, see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187828/wrong-pdf-bookmark-for-bibliography-chapter/188040#188040

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for your answer. I tried `\clearpage
\phantomsection
\printindex
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}`. Now the problem is that the Index ToC entry points to the start of the Index instead of displaying the Index title.

Comment: @PierPaolo: I will look into your code

Comment: @PierPaolo: I am little bit confused: You do want to have an ToC entry for the Index and this should be hyperlink to your Index? If this is the case, then the code you tried (see your comment) is correct, after compiling twice. Or do you mean the Toc itself, `Indice` in Italian?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: You are right, but now the link points to the first voice of the Index instead of pointing to the title. I looked here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172352/correct-hyperlink-to-the-index/172375 , but I could not solve the "new" problem.

Comment: @PierPaolo: You mean the title `Indice analitico`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes. It's the Italian for Index, I left it because I reduced an actual document to a MWE.

Comment: @PierPaolo: How do you notice, that it links to the first entry of your `Indice analitico` instead of linking to the title? In your MWE there is just one index entry, `section`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15829/discussion-between-pier-paolo-and-christian-hupfer).

Comment: Have you ever been able to resolve the issue? Can you provide a self answer or was Heikos solution helping you as well? If so, we could close this as duplicate to Heikos solution.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Heiko Oberdiek's answer ([here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172352/correct-hyperlink-to-the-index/172375)) helped get the right page from the “Index” link in the ToC, but didn't solve the problem posted specifically in that question, i.e. the fact that the link points to the first entry in the Index rather than the Index title (`\indexname`). It's not really a problem, though.

Comment: How about [KOMA book: correct hyperlink to the index?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208478) and/or [Link to index in TOC points does not point to index, but to whatever is right before index](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65255)

Comment: @Johannes_B: the link to your question solves completely the problem for the class `scrbook` (which I actually use now instead of the standard classes). However, it generates a spurious blank page after the index itself and moreover it affects the page style: the first page of the index has a different style than the one I defined with `\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{...}` and the following page as the header, even though I loaded the package `emptypage` to explicitly suppress it.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I corrected the wrong page style with `\renewcommand*{\indexpagestyle}{...}` but the spurious blank (not really, it still has the header) page is still there.

Comment: `indexpagestyle` is the right keyword. the default with KOMA-classes is, i think, `cleardoublepage=empty`, so i guess for this part, a new question is in order. But back to the topic at hand, what to do with this question? To be honest, i haven't even tested your MWE. Shall i look into the matter, or dupe it as one of the above linked Qs?

Comment: @Johannes_B: the original question is solved thanks to the answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172352/correct-hyperlink-to-the-index/172375), so IMO this thread can be closed as a duplicate of the linked question. The spurious blank page is an issue that is about `scrbook` and I plan to investigate it before posting another question. Thank you for your time. `:)`

Comment: VtC as dupe as discussed in the last comments. Looking forward to the new question, if it comes :-)